# dynamic auto update highcharts using ajax from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, highcharts

I am able to have one dynamic line using Ajax now i want to have 2 to 3 lines more and want to take the live data from the database. can anyone help me with this two queries please. firstly for 2 lines and second how to get live data which updates every second from database and plot it on high chart. it would be great.

Comment: Please don't post questions twice. Also, your question is way to broad in scope. The site guidelines on asking questions are here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic